# How to display Push button of Git on Android Studio 3.3.1 toolbar?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I'm a beginner of Git and Github, Now I submit the change to remote Github server by clicking the menu item  VCS -> Git -> Push... on Android Studio.

The image is my toolbar of Git. There are only some buttons.

[image]

I hope the Push button can be displayed on main toolbar, how can I do?

BTW, I have read the article https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-git-in-android-studio--cms-30514, but I can't find the step of the image on Android Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can. Here's how. First go to,

> File > Settings > Appearance & Behaviour > Main Toolbar

& Navigate to

> Navigation Bar Toolbar > NavBarVcsGroup > VcsNavbarToolbarActions

[image: settings window]

Next click on Add After button.

[image: Add After Window]

Then find Push under Vesrion Control System. Select it and Clcik OK. Apply and Ok all the windows. That's it you can now see the Push button in Git Toolbar.

Comment: I followed this but it's still not showing in the toolbar? I even shut down Android Studio completely and restarted, but no joy.

Comment: @WilliamT.Mallard Please check whether you added it to `Main Toolbar > Main Toolbar Settings > VCS Actions`.

Comment: Should have updated this, but it's actually in Android Studio -> Preferences... -> Appearance and Behavior -> Menus and Toolbars -> Navigation Bar Toolbar -> NavBarVcsGroup -> VcsNavbarToolbarActions. *phew*

Comment: @WilliamT.Mallard Thanks! I edited the answer to include the correct location. Also it seems like it's actually _misspelled_ as `VcsNavbarToobarActions` in Android Studio lmao